# Upload file php and send parameter in Yii (PHP)

Tags: php, post, yii, parameters, firebug

I want to upload file and send parameter to server at the same time (submit). I'm using  Yii framework in PHP and in my site form contains activeFileField, activeDropDownList.

**View.php**

```
echo CHtml:beginForm('','post',array('enctype'=>'multipart/form-data'));
```

> >
>   echo CHtml::activeDropDownList($model, 'backupNo', $data);
>
> >
>   echo CHtml::activeFileField($model, 'upgradeFile', array('size'=>40''));

When Page is rendered to me, I see dropDownlist component in browser

```
<select id="DeviceConfigurationBackup_backupNo" name="DeviceConfigurationBackup[backupNo]">
<option value="1">1</option>
```

And also, in firebug I see file and parameter are send to my site (controller)

> > Parameters (Firebug)
> >               **DeviceConfigurationBackup...**  4
> >               **DeviceConfigurationBackup...**
> >               **DeviceConfigurationBackup...**  Credit.html
> >                                     **yt0**     upload

However I can not get the parameter inside in my controller.php. I check 5 combination, but none of the them is working..

```
$backupNo1 = $_REQUEST['DeviceConfigurationBackup[backupNo]'];

$backupNo2 = Yii::app()->request-getParam('backupNo');  

$backupNo3 = $_POST['DeviceConfigurationBackup[backupNo]'];

$backupNo4 = $_POST['backupNo'];

$backupNo5 = $_REQUEST['DeviceConfigurationBackup']['name']['backupNo]'];
```

What is the problem? or how can I get the parameter and file? OR I wonder, Is it possible to send additional parameters when uploading a file in yii (php)?

Answer (score 0):

You are missing a leading underscore in the name of the superglobals. E.g. it's `$_POST`, not `$POST`